# HttpURLConnection Cannot openConnection

Tags: android, httpurlconnection

```
@Override
protected Void doInBackground(String... params) {
    String type = params[0];
    String url= "http://10.0.2.2/login.php" ;
    if(type.equals("Singin"))  {
        try {
            URL Singin_url = new URL(url);
            //Cannot not resolve method 'openConnection()'
            HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

Why won't it let me OpenConnection ??
and i cant go forward because it says 'connection' not initialized

Comment: i'm using this in a class that extends AsyncTask

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to call the `openConnection()` method on the `URL` object `Singin_url`. You are calling it on a `String` object.

```
@Override
protected Void doInBackground(String... params)
{
    String type = params[0];
    String url= "http://10.0.2.2/login.php" ;
    if(type.equals("Singin"))
    {
        try {
            URL Singin_url = new URL(url);
            HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection)Singin_url.openConnection();    
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }    
    }
    return null;
}
```

Also your variable name first character should be in lower case, like `signInUrl`.